# How do I ensure that Rails does not generate test Test::Unit tests when I use a generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am using RSpec, but Rails insists on generating Test::Unit tests. Maybe there is a configuration I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using rails 2 then you do:

ruby script/generate rspec_model Foo

using Rails 3 check out this example:

http://paulbarry.com/articles/2010/01/13/customizing-generators-in-rails-3

Comment: Ah, the config.generators setting. It's hard to find a good documentation for what you can use for that block.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 3, you need the rspec-rails integration gem from github: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

The instructions are there on Github, but you will need to run

```
script/rails generate rspec:install
```

From the README:

"RSpec is registered with Rails as the test framework, so whenever you generate application components like models, controllers, etc, RSpec specs are generated instead of Test::Unit tests."